# in XSLT how to remove white space in namespace headers getting output

Tags: xml, xslt

How to remove white space in xslt namespace header

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                 xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/2010/FpML-4-9"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:mtc="OTC_Matching_11-0" xmlns:rm="OTC_RM_11-0"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="OTC_RM_11-0 /xmls/OTC/OTC_RM_11-0.xsd 
                 OTC_Matching_11-0/xmls/OTC/OTC_Matching_11-0.xsd http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ /xmls/OTC/soap-envelope.xsd http://www.fpml.org/2010/FpML-4-9 /xmls/OTC/fpml-main-4-9.xsd"  >

        </env:Envelope>
```

out should be in single line this header files insted of getting new line

Comment: I have tried xml:space="preserve" it implemets for entire xml but i need only for header file

Comment: What exactly is the output you want for that?

Comment: XSLT doesn't offer that level of customization. The whitespaces inside a markup tag change nothing to the XML data, and therefore it cannot matter to you. At best you may want to send an XML payload compactly to avoid overhead, and that is what XSLT does by default, or you want a pretty print of the resulting XML document, and for that you use output indent="yes". There is no rationale for in-between.

Comment: Expected output :                                                                                         env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/2010/FpML-4-9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mtc="OTC_Matching_11-0" xmlns:rm="OTC_RM_11-0" xsi:schemaLocation="OTC_RM_11-0 /xmls/OTC/OTC_RM_11-0.xsd OTC_Matching_11-0/xmls/OTC/OTC_Matching_11-0.xsd http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ /xmls/OTC/soap-envelope.xsd http://www.fpml.org/2010/FpML-4-9 /xmls/OTC/fpml-main-4-9.xsd" >

Comment: in single line remaing all <header><body>  it should expected asusual like newline

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following tags in your `stylesheet` file to specify the output as `XML` and to strip spaces:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- add those 2 tags at the begining of your stylesheet to specify that the output is XML format and to strip the spaces -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" /> 
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
            ...
            ...
            ...
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that, in order to decrease the size of the XML files, thus improve the transmission speed in the network as well as the parsing speed/processing speed at the receiving host. Empty nodes are often converted as `<node/>` instead of `<node></node>` by `XSLT` processors.

You could also `linarize` your XML file before sending it, if you have to send a lot of information at once.

Comment: yes , output method="xml" used even through getting same only, entire xml getting in single line